# How to connect Oracle database from Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server in ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oracle-sqldeveloper, mssql-jdbc

I have created an ASP.NET MVC application in which I have to connect to Oracle 9 database and access its data. I don't have an Oracle driver installed in my Visual Studio.

I got one answer that we can connect Oracle database with Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server. But I don't have any idea of JDBC....

If anyone know about it then please let me know...Thanks in advance...

Comment: You need to install an Oracle driver of some kind.

Comment: “JDBC driver for SQL Server” is a driver for SQL Server, not Oracle.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid for your response. Do you know some other way to access Oracle db from MVC application.

Comment: You simply need to install the Oracle ODBC driver. Here's one guide. https://tech2677.wordpress.com/2016/12/04/asp-net-mvc-5-entity-framework-connect-with-oracle-database-database-first-approach/